# Como adicionar um array com valores dinâmicos em um objeto com propriedades dinâmicas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual a melhor maneira de criar e popular um array dinamicamente e inseri-lo em uma propriedade dinâmica de um objeto?

Podemos utilizar o seguinte cenário:

```js
$(function() {

  const products = {};

  const items = $('.items .item');
  $(items).each(function(i) {
    /* As propriedades do objeto devem ser o data-type e cada propriedade
     * terá um array com os data-id
     */
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <span class="item" data-id="1" data-type="eletronics">Phone</span>
  <span class="item" data-id="1" data-type="sports">Ball</span>
  <span class="item" data-id="2" data-type="sports">Shoes</span>
  <span class="item" data-id="3" data-type="sports">T-Shirt</span>
  <span class="item" data-id="2" data-type="eletronics">TV</span>
</div>
```

O resultado esperado seria esse:

```
// console.log(products);

{
    eletronics: [1, 2],
    sports: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: Dentro do seu `array` os valores `eletronics`, `sports` vem dinamicamente ?

Comment: Isso, são dinâmicos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseado no que você me passou, fiz algumas alterações e consegui replicar o seu resultado.

```
<script>
var products = {};

$(function() {

  const items = $('.items .item');
  $(items).each(function(i) {       
    let type = $(this).data("type");
    let id = $(this).data("id");
    if(products[type] == undefined){
            products[type] = [];
    }
    products[type].push(id);
  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, funcionou certinho!